# How can we call SharedArray in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a function and I want to call it in the main function. all of arguments is `sharedArray` and we have one variable that is `type`. when I want to run the program I got an error.

```
@everywhere type dty{T <: Real}
    ...... (some variable)
end

@everywhere function func2!(v::dty,
                          out::SharedArray,
                          out2::SharedArray)
........
end

function func1()
...
out    = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n,m)
out2   = SharedArray{Float64,2}(n,m)
......
func2!(v , out, out2)
end
```

Error:

```
MethodError: no method matching func2!(::dty{Float64}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::SharedArray{Float64,2}, ::SharedArray{Float64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  func2!(::dty, ::SharedArray, ::SharedArray) at In[3]:64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define

```
@everywhere function func2!(v,
                          out,
                          out2)
```

and it'll work. Those dispatch designations don't do anything for performance. If you want to restrict it to "things which are arrays", then you can do

```
@everywhere function func2!(v,
                          out::AbstractArray,
                          out2::AbstractArray)
```

Again, this doesn't hurt performance and is only for setting dispatches and throwing errors. What happened in your code is you had `out::SharedArray`, when then threw an error when `out` was not a `SharedArray` (your example doesn't show why it wasn't a `SharedArray`, but the error message is saying `out` was a `Matrix`)

Comment: out was a matrix before I wanted to parallel the code. but matrix is array 2D and when I use typeof(out) I find out it can be Array. so I used it as sharedArray

Comment: Right, but if you do it like this then each version will work, no matter what array you put in there.